# box.com TAG_ITEM_CREATE event

Tags: box-api

In the box docs, it states that the event `TAG_ITEM_CREATE` occurs when '**A Tag was added to a file or folder**'. Is there any way to find out which folder/file the tag was added to ,without iterating them all?

Answer (score 0):

If you're [fetching events for a Box enterprise](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise) you can have Box perform server-side filtering of events. However, when [fetching events for a standard Box account](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-for-a-user) you must do the filtering in your application. The `next_stream_position` parameter can be used to set a lower time bound for the events that you receive, which can significantly reduce the amount of metadata that you have to sort through.

**EDIT:** Answering questions from comment.

> **Q**: Not sure how filtering events helps me work out which folder has been tagged?

The `event` object that's returned to you will look like this:

```
{
   "next_stream_position":1348790499819,
   "entries":[
      {
         "event_type":"TAG_ITEM_CREATE",
         "source":{
            "type":"folder",
            "id":"11446498",
         ... more event info ...
         }
      },
      ... more events ...
   ]
}
```

In your application you can look for those events whose `event_type` is `TAG_ITEM_CREATE`. You can then use the `source` to determine which particular resource was tagged.

> **Q**: Are you saying that I can ask for all folders changed since a given TAG_ITEM_CREATE event?

No. Think of the 'next_stream_position` property as a proxy for a timestamp. You can use it to tell Box, "Tell me about all the events that occurred *after* this 'position' in time." But this will still give you all *types* of events that occurred. You'll have to select the events of interest in your application.

This is one of the big differences in the Enterprise- and User-facing APIs. In an Enterprise  you can tell Box, "I want info on all the TAG_ITEM_CREATE events that occurred in the Enterprise between yesterday and today."  In the User-facing API the best you can tell Box is effectively, "I want info on all events that occurred in this User's box since yesterday."

Comment: Not sure how filtering events helps me work out _which_ folder has been tagged? Are you saying that I can ask for all folders changed since a given TAG_ITEM_CREATE event?

Comment: I'm using the Java SDK and the source item is always null on the event. This is happening in version 2 and the latest code. Not sure if this is a bug in the API or the Java SDK.  I'll do some investigation and update.  Thanks for clearing up the expected behavour though - your initial answer makes much more sense now.

Comment: Ah! Sorry for the initial confusion. You might capture some of the HTTPS traffic between you and Box using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (Win) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (Mac). This will help you to determine whether Box is sending you the expected data.

Comment: As I suspected, the API is not returning the source with the event:   `{"chunk_size":1,"next_stream_position":1396624522869,"entries":[{"type":"event","event_id":"45d0ec20a09b0a606119b99fe574b6b05b328b5f","created_by":{"type":"user","id":"210999093","name":"me","login":"me@gmail.com"},"created_at":"2014-04-04T08:14:58-07:00","recorded_at":"2014-04-04T08:14:59-07:00","event_type":"TAG_ITEM_CREATE","session_id":"1433097989533eac15fffff","source":null}]}`

Comment: A ticket has been raised for this issue (#568353) - you can't view the progress unfortunately - due to another bug in the ticketing system :-(